# How to get smallest or biggest position in array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to get the smallest or biggest position in arrays javascript?

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford", "Fiat", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
} //I want to get car[i] (car[0])
```

How to get the smallest position "cars[0]" or biggest position "cars[5]" value???  Any tips, or code snippets are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `cars[0]` and `cars[cars.length - 1]` will give you first and last elements respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cars[0]` or `cars[cars.length - 1]` will get your values. But you can also use `cars.shift()` and `cars.pop()` to achieve the same, although these methods will alter the array.